# How to group and calculate the total sum of items in subdocuments using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grouping, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. I am trying to get total sum of my subdocuments but I did not get the desired result. my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf9vjLy1/6/)

The result I got

```
Summary:
1000
100
50
100
100
Total:undefined
```

The result I'm expecting

```
Summary:
1000
100
50
100
100
Total:1350
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="mani in items">
      <p ng-repeat ="rohit in mani.colorshades ">
      {{rohit.order_quantity}}
      </p>
    </li>
    <p class="length">Total:{{items.length}}</p>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [{
"_id": "56f91708b7d0d40b0036bc09",
"colorshades": [
    {
    "_id": "56f9177fb7d0d40b0036bc0c",
    "order_quantity": "1000",
    },
    {
    "_id": "56f9177fb7d0d40b0036bc0b",
    "order_quantity": "100",
    },
    {
    "_id": "56f919d7b7d0d40b0036bc13",
    "order_quantity": "50",
    }]
},
{
"_id": "56f367e6a7d3730b008d296a",
"colorshades": [
    {
      "_id": "56f3680ba7d3730b008d296c",
      "order_quantity": "100",
    }
]
},
{
"_id": "56e7af485b15b20b00cad881",
"colorshades": [
    {
    "_id": "56e7af7b5b15b20b00cad882",
    "order_quantity": "100",
    }
]
}];

$scope.getTotals = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item.colorshades.length; i++) {
        var item = $scope.item.colorshades[i];
        total += (item.order_quantity);
    }
    return total;
};
```

my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf9vjLy1/6/)

Comment: HTML is used to display content and interact, JS is used to execute code. You need to execute code in JS to calculate a sum, maybe you should start from a JS basic guide

Comment: have updated my controller and tried to get the total

Comment: well done! Now display the result of your function, so change `{{items.length}}` with `{{getTotals()}}`

Comment: i have but not able to get the answer so pls look at my fiddle...

Comment: Sorry but it seems you don't really know how to code in JS. You have a `$scope.items` array, inside you have objects containing array of objects. You need at least 2 cycle to get that sum, but you need to know how to cycle arrays and get properties correctly... You should really start from the basics or you won't be able to achieve your result (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a two level loops, the code should be like that (don't forget to cast the strings by parseInt otherwise you will have a concatenation) :

```
$scope.getTotals = function () {
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.items[i].colorshades.length; j++) {
      total += parseInt(($scope.items[i].colorshades[j].order_quantity));
    }
}
return total;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method available to calculate total order quantity. You need to have a controller method to calculate it and html can point it to that method or $scope variable in which total quantity is stored

Comment: have updated my controller and tried to get the total

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
$scope.getTotals = function () {
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
  var item = $scope.items[i].colorshades;
  for(var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
    total = total + parseInt(item[j].order_quantity);
   }
  }
  return total;
 };
}
```